# Shopify, TypeError: $(...).jcarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify, jcarousel

So I have seen the other questions with this same title, and I don't think I am running into the same problems they had (Specifically because I am not using Drupal and the files do seem to be loading in the page header as shown below). I understand that it cannot find that function, but I don't know why. This is the code inside the theme.liquid head where it sets up the javascript and styles:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" />

  {% assign maxmeta = 155 %}
  {% if template contains 'product' %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ product.description | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: maxmeta | escape }}" />
  {% elsif template contains 'page' %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ page.content | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: maxmeta | escape }}" />
  {% elsif template == 'index' and shop.description != '' %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ shop.description }}" />
  {% endif %}


  {{ 'skinCustom.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'jquery-1.4.2.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'jquery.jcarousel.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

  {% if template == 'index' %}
   <title>{{ shop.name }}</title>
  {% elsif template == '404' %}
    <title>Page Not Found | {{ shop.name }}</title>
  {% else %}
   <title>{{ page_title }} | {{ shop.name }}</title>
  {% endif %}

  {% include 'fb-open-graph' %}

  {% case settings.header_font %}
  {% when "Rancho, cursive" %}
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  {% when "'Amatic SC', cursive" %}
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  {% when "'Sancreek', cursive" %}
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sancreek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  {% when "'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif" %}
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  {% endcase %}

  {{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}{% if template contains 'product' and settings.main_image_display == 'Lightbox' %}
  {{ 'jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}{% endif %}
  {{ 'modernizr.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}

  {% if template contains 'customers' %}
    {{ "shopify_common.js" | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
    {{ "customer_area.js"  | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% endif %}

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ vertical: true, scroll: 1, start: 3 });
    });

    </script>

  {{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}

  {{ content_for_header }}
```

When the page renders I get the following (I edited out the extra stuff not pertaining to this question). I put arrows pointing to the reference of the js and styling page that jcarousel depends on. I had an example of this working in a separate file before I tried to move it into the Shopify project.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  --> <link href="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0212/5406/t/1/assets/skinCustom.css?241" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all"  />
  --> <script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0212/5406/t/1/assets/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?241" type="text/javascript"></script>
  --> <script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0212/5406/t/1/assets/jquery.jcarousel.min.js?241" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <link href="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0212/5406/t/1/assets/style.css?241" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all"  />
  <script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0212/5406/t/1/assets/modernizr.js?241" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/shopify/option_selection.js?aaf2a68ed9671e345bbc7eef1e63563c51bde6eb" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
   ERROR HERE -->    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ vertical: true, scroll: 1, start: 3 });
    });

    </script>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/global/theme-controls.css" type="text/css" />


</head>
```

The only thing I can imagine might be happening is one of the other script files is messing this up. But I am not really sure how I would debug that besides taking out the other script files. If anyone has run into a similar issue or has some insight on this I would greatly appreciate it. None of the other questions seemed to get an answer beyond just incorrect implementation (like leaving that script out of the head). I might be doing something dumb, but I have researched and looked over this numerous times and I can't see what it is.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Why are you loading jquery twice? One possible issue is with the dollar sign used by jQuery. Try replacing it with `jQuery` so you have `jQuery('#mycarousel')` or try using jquery's noconflict mode. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I looked over that so many times... guess I needed a second pair of eyes. The issue is just that, loading jquery twice is messing it up. I did this because when I initially tried to use jcarousel it said it could not find jquery which it was dependent on. So I added it myself, just assuming it wasn't already loading it. Thanks for the response. I have been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: What happens if you have all the order correct and you have no conflicts. and it STILL doesn't get recognized (but you can see in the consoles it is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting my comment from above into response form.

Two issues with this. First, you are loading jQuery twice. Don't do that. Second, jQuery's use of `$` can conflict with other javascript libraries so you should either use `jQuery` or use jQuery's [noconflict mode.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

As @gaoshan88 commented I was loading jquery twice. Because when I initially added just the jcarousel.js script it said there was no jquery file. So I added it myself again, not knowing that shopify also adds the most recent version via google.apis. Not quite sure why it gave me that error in the first place with jquery, but when I take the google.apis script referene out it worked. Thank you for the quick response I appreciate it.

Comment: Order matters when loading scripts.  Order them based on their dependencies on other scripts. The jcarousel.js file should be added after the jquery.js file, because jcarousel depends on jquery.  Visually it becomes apparent: `$().jcarousel`

Comment: Ya that must have been the issue, I thought I loaded jcarousel as the last script the first time I tried, but I guess that google.apis one for jquery was below it.